# Record with uncompressed format for faster cutting with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I am having difficulty cutting videos accurately.

This is the current command I am using. The problem with this command is that
I have to re-encode the data.

```
ffmpeg -i file_name.webm -ss 00:00:00 -strict -2 -to 00:00:00 new_file_name_3.webm
```

The codec I am using is VP9 with the webm container ([docs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9))

This works fine, but it could take longer for large videos.

I would like to know if there is a way to record with ffmpeg in an uncompressed format which would
allow for accurate cutting without needing to re-encode the data. Once all of the cutting work is
complete I code stick it all together then do a final encoding.

Is this an option in ffmpeg? Is so how can I accomplish it?

Comment: Have you already discarded input seeking and codec copy as it is mentioned [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking)? That is the fastest way to cut videos but, as the same page says, it *might* not be accurate.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. For my case accuracy >> time. I would rather have something that is slow and accurate, which is what I am doing now, over fast and inaccurate.

Comment: So you want to use rawvideo instead of VP9? Instead of `ffmpeg -i input file_name.webm` use `ffmpeg -i input -f rawvideo output`